# Scala - Using parametric to specify type in function

Tags: scala

Good day,

I have an assignment in university where we needed to write a parser for a certain language. One of the core features of this language was writing an equals method for both NumCs and StringCs (The Number and String representation in the core language). Both of these method would evaluate to BoolV(x), where x is either true or false (BoolV stands for the Boolean Value in this language).

I have succeeded in doing so with the following code (Please note that all inputs are ExprC, which is the superclass of all Core representations of functionality. Moreover, the `interp` functions take care of translating the ExprC into Values):

```
def str_cmp(l: ExprC, r: ExprC): BoolV = (interp(l), interp(r)) match {
  case (StringV(x), StringV(y)) => BoolV(x == y)
  case _ => throw NotStringException("Atleast one argument value does not evaluate to a String.")
}

def num_cmp(l: ExprC, r: ExprC): BoolV = (interp(l), interp(r)) match {
  case (NumV(x), NumV(y)) => BoolV(x == y)
  case _ => throw NotNumberException("Atleast one argument value does not evaluate to a number.")
}
```

As you might notice, these functions are very much alike; only the type that is checked changes (As well as the exception, but these are both subclasses from the same exception).

Now I was wondering whether there is some utility that would produce something like the following functionality:

```
def compare[A](l: ExprC, r: ExprC): BoolV = (interp(l), interp(r)) match {
 case (A(x), A(y)) => BoolV(x == y)
 case _ => throw NotValidArgument("Atleast one argument value does not evaluate to " + A + ".")
```

This would mean that one could specify in one way another the type that the interp of both `l` and `r` has to result in, in order for the compare method to evaluate rather than to throw an error. I know that the above code is by no way correct syntax, but I was wondering whether there is a way to code this functionality within Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ClassTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) is probably what you are looking for to solve your problem:

```
import reflect.ClassTag

def compare[T : ClassTag](l: ExprC, r: ExprC): BoolV = {
    val ct = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    (interp(l), interp(r)) match {
      case (ct(x), ct(y)) => BoolV(x == y)
      case _ => throw new Exception("At least one argument value does not evaluate to " + ct + ".")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The way these are being called are in two different ways; the String compare is called when two Expressions are compared (these expressions should evaluate to Strings) and the same goes for Number compare. The reason I want to pass on the generic type is because I do not want a string compare to succeed with two expressions which evaluate to a number. In the code you have created, this is not the case.

Comment: Ok then but I don't really get why Strings would evaluate to Numbers ..

Comment: It is a somewhat abstract construction, but you have a Core language notation `EqStringC(l: ExprC, r:ExprC)` which has two ExprC's as attributes. These ExprCs can evaluate to either a Boolean, Number or String after interpreting these. Therefore, I want to make sure EqStringC only succeeds when both ExprC's evaluate to StringVs

Comment: I edited my answer with the code you need, give me feedback if you're able to use it or not :)

Comment: This looks exactly like the functionality I wanted! Thanks a lot!